# Mapping multi level navigation in react, ok to use foreach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Been reading react docs and it seems like like using foreach or for is kind of anti pattern in react. 
So was wondering how to solve the problem of having 4 level navigation spread to different components;

The template is similar to firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides, with the primary menu and secondary menu, and then following side menu with multiple levels, lets say 2 in this case.

The menus are delivered from gatsby in this format:

```
[
  {
    "title": "About",
    "url": "/about/",
    "target": "",
    "wordpress_parent": 0,
    "wordpress_children": null
  },
  {
    "title": "Page 1",
    "url": "/page1/",
    "target": "",
    "wordpress_parent": 0,
    "wordpress_children": [
      {
        "title": "Guides",
        "url": "/page1/guides/",
        "wordpress_children": null
      },
      {
        "title": "Reference",
        "url": "/page1/reference/",
        "wordpress_children": [
          {
            "url": "/page1/reference/browser-support/",
            "title": "Browser support",
            "wordpress_parent": 71
          },
          {
            "url": "/page1/reference/getting-started/",
            "title": "Getting started",
            "wordpress_parent": 71
          },
          {
            "url": "/page1/reference/getting-started/setup/",
            "title": "Setup",
            "wordpress_parent": 71
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And the main template is looking like this

```
   <Layout>
    <Header />
    <Layout>
      <Sidebar />
      <Layout style={{ padding: '0 24px 24px' }}>
      <Content >
      {props.children}
    </Content>
    </Layout>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
```

Header and Sidebar should get their menu properties trough this layout.

Since my background is from angular, i would firstly go trough the object with foreach make objects for sidebar and header and insert them as options, but as the foreach is not a pattern in react i am unsure what the correct approach would be.

What would be correct way to solve this in React?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach would be to use `map` on the array. `forEach` is discouraged because it mutates the array it is called upon. `map`, however, returns the new array, which is almost always a safer option. However I'm not entirely sure what are you going to do with this array, so my answer is a bit of a guess.

Also, I wouldn't say that `forEach` of `for` loop is an anti-pattern; they both are an important part of javascript syntax and workflow, the only thing to keep in mind is their proper usage.